# Save and retrieve images from mysql database

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

For Save Image I am try this code.

```
MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(string.Format("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd=123456;"));
mycon.Open()
FileStream  fs = new FileStream("b.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
int sizee = (int)fs.Length;
byte[] rawData = new byte[sizee+1];
fs.Read(rawData, 0, sizee);
fs.Close();
new MySqlCommand(string.Format("INSERT INTO image VALUES(NULL,'{0}',{1})", rawData, sizee), mycon).ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This code is work fine and  insert data successfully.But when i trying to retrieve data it throw an exception **No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.**

Here is the code which is use to retrieve data.

```
MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(string.Format("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd=123456;"));
        mycon.Open();
        MySqlCommand mycom = new MySqlCommand("Select * from image", mycon);
       MySqlDataReader myData = mycom.ExecuteReader();
       myData.Read();
       int filesize = myData.GetInt32(myData.GetOrdinal("size"));
       byte[] mydatya=new byte[filesize];
       myData.GetBytes(myData.GetOrdinal("myImage"), 0, mydatya, 0, filesize);
       var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
       bitmapImage.BeginInit();
       bitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(mydatya);
       bitmapImage.EndInit();
```

Comment: try this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/image_asp.aspx

Comment: Does your object in the retrieval code have to be a BitmapImage instead of something like a System.Drawing.Image object?   I'm not very familiar with the BitmapImage object, but the error sounds like it's related to that.   I'm thinking MySQL is not really a factor here, but to verify that I would test the full cycle image flow to make sure the byte[] is what you're expecting (maybe move the image construction code into the Save method temporarily just to verify it's able to create the image from the original bytes without worrying about tramsission of the bytes to and from the database)

Comment: You can't pass image data directly in the query string like that.  To test, save the image data to disk as a file and try to open it.  You need a parameterized query, not a composited query string.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally considered better practice to put only references to files in a database and physically save the files in a folder.

Comment: @Orbling: Yes you are right, but I think (hope) the answer/comment has its value. When he fixes his current problem and continues to save the files in the database, maybe he will have to ask something like 'how can I retrieve the content from a huge crashed mysql database' in several weeks.

Comment: Aye, having large BLOBs in a database is a recipe for pain in most respects and usually wholly unnecessary.