# WPF Chat List Box - With user Image display

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, chat

Hello there i am working on a WPF Chat Application , i would like to save users pics at database and i would like to load each user with his/her pic to the friends list box and here is my current code but i dont know how to start with this .

```
        private void LoadFriends(Client.State client)
    {
        foreach (Client.Structures.Society.Friend friend in client.Friends.Values)
        {
            Friends_listBox.Items.Add(friend.Name);
            FriendsCount++;
        }
    }
```

i know how to add an item to a list box with Xaml code like this :

```
            <ListBoxItem Background="LightCoral" Foreground="Red"

         FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold">

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Image Source="/my_App;component/Img.ico" Height="30"></Image>

                <TextBlock Text="Coffie"></TextBlock>

            </StackPanel>

        </ListBoxItem>
```

but i dont know to do this with C# code ...

an how i store users pics to database ??

any idea about this ?

Comment: create a class(let's call it `Friend`) that holds 2 properties(`string` Name, `ImageSource` Image) and make it implement INPC. Now in your code-behind create an `ObservableCollection<Friend> FriendsList` and set the `ItemSource` of your `ListBox` to `FriendsList`. In xaml set the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` to be a `DataTemplate` for `Type="{x:Type local:Friend}"`. In this DataTemplate now have your `StackPanel` with Child `Image` whose `Source` can Bind to `Image` from DataContext and similarly a `TextBlock` -> `Name`. Also set  DataContext of the xaml View to the code-behind holding `FriendsList`

Comment: Thank you , i have created a class called Friend like this


`public class Friend : Interfaces.IKnownPerson
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public System.Windows.Media.ImageSource FriendAvatar
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }`

but don't how what is the next step to load the images ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think you should first spend some time learning basics in WPF than jumping straight into pulling together multiple aspects in an app.

[Maybe this could help - a sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfbl5p9m5ra1u2p/WpfApplication16.rar)

^^ Project has everything I stated in my comment on your question. I've chosen to not base this sample on MVVM cos that might just confuse you further(please just use the sample as an idea and do look into MVVM if you havent done so already)

Try to see if you can first understand the sample before dealing with databases and if not get a book on WPF and start reading. Can't really go any more basic than this.

In the sample,

`Friend.cs` should be similar to what you posted with the addition of the INPC implementation.

`MainWindow.xaml` should show how the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` holds a `DataTemplate` and is setup to Bind to properties in it's `DataContext`

`MainWindow.xaml.cs` should show how to populate items in the `FriendsList` collection and also how `DataContext` is set for the `MainWindow`.

If you're comfortable with all of this(and probably read a bit into `Style`'s and Resources), then you can start thinking about how your going to be using a db to populate the source of `FriendsList`

Either just make a new question for that at that stage or refer to previous questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926105/save-image-source-to-database), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435151/save-and-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database) and [this](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/62133-c-and-databases-part-1-high-level-intro-to-working-with-databases-from-c/)

Comment: thanx really for this big help , and i understand code but really this is first time i use  in my work and i got this message now

`Error 1 The type or namespace name 'CallerMemberNameAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\WpfApplication16\WpfApplication16\Friend.cs 46 50 WpfApplication16
`

Comment: Your welcome. WPF is great. Start with the basics and work your way up. You can find loads of help with starter level things in SO and just by "googling". Do pick up a book like [Sams Teach Yourself WPF in 24 Hours](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Sams-Teach-Yourself-WPF-Hours/dp/0672329859/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1371864037&sr=1-3&keywords=wpf) to learn the basics fast. Good Luck :)

Comment: i am already a C# programmer , but i am new to wpf although i created a few programs using wpf ,, but really i need an explaining about my issues , that's all , thank you mate .

Comment: @user1994619 `CallerMemberNameAttribute` was added in .NET4.5. I've updated the INPC implementation and project target framework to .NET4. Try downloading the sample again and you should have it work fine